# Title's type is called by Netsuite in some unknown way

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, frontend, netsuite

I am dealing with a confusing problem about front-end of Website.

All the titles of sub pages of this website are replaced by [Object Object].

Please Someone give me some suggestions about it.

Thank you

Comment: You're using an object in a place where a string is expected. You probably should be using a property in the object. Without actual code it's impossible to be more specific.

Comment: Is this a Sitebuilder site or SuiteCommerce Advanced?

Comment: It is SuiteCommerce Advanced.

Comment: Ok. You really do need to add some specifics. The handlebars template that lays out the title you are looking at would be helpful.